# Disable button until a number is reached

Tags: javascript, html, button, numbers

So I have a code so when I press a button a number goes up.
This is the html:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="javascript:btnClick()">+1</button>
```

This is the JavaScript:

```
 function btnClick(){
timesClicked += 1;
    document.getElementById('timesClicked').innerHTML = timesClicked;
return true 
}
```

So I have a button that has +1 so when I press it the number goes up
I need a button that is disabled until that number gets to 5 for example then becomes clickable, is that possible? I'm still learning Javascript,
All help is appreciated.

Comment: Should the text/action of the button change when it is clicked more than 5 times? Based on your question, one will not be able to click the button to increase the number because it is disabled (as demonstrated by my answer's code snippet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the button is disabled, a user cannot interact with it.
Try the following

```js
window.onload=function() {
    var count =0;
    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
        
      count++;
      if(count === 5) {
         this.innerHTML = "5 clicks reached!";
      }
  });
    };
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

Comment: @Pennel: great. You can accept this as an answer if it works for you. You can try the one with css as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```js
document.getElementById("button").disabled = true;
timesClicked = 0;

function btnClick(){
   timesClicked += 1;
   document.getElementById('timesClicked').innerHTML = timesClicked;

   if(timesClicked > 5){
       document.getElementById("button").disabled = false;
   }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="btnClick()">+1</button>
```

Comment: This answer is amazing and the demo totally works! **];)**

Answer (score 0):

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("[data-click-vote]"), function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener("click", vote);
});

function vote() {
  this.innerHTML = this.value=Math.min(++this.value, 5);
}
```

```html
<button value="0" name="movie1" data-click-vote>+1</button> The Revenant<br>
<button value="0" name="movie2" data-click-vote>+1</button> Dracula<br>
<button value="0" name="movie3" data-click-vote>+1</button> The Usual Suspect<br>
```

- Multiple buttons
- Updates simultaneously `value` and `innerHTML`
- You can submit the values using a `<form>`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your requirement with JS and CSS as in the below solution.
You haven't tagged it with CSS but you might want to look at this as well.

Button is simply a disabled span. Clicks are registered and when the count requirement is satisfied, it springs to life and handles your clicks with the actual handler code. (You can add a handler instead of printing a click count)

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var count = 1;
  document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() {

    count++;
    this.innerHTML = "+" + count;
    if (count >= 5) {
      this.className = "btnenabled";
      this.innerHTML = "Print Click Count!";
      if(count > 5) {
        document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML= "Click Count is " + count;
      }
     }
  });
};
```

```css
.btnenabled {
  width:200px;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
}
.btnenabled:hover {
    background-color:purple;
}

.btndisabled {
  width:200px;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
  background-color: grey;
  color: #F0F0F0;
  font-weight: 100;
}
```

```html
<span id="btn" class="btndisabled">  +1 </span>
<span id="counter"></span>
```